# Find values that make up an aggregated query

Tags: unit-testing, plsql

I have the following table in plsql

```
Company | StoreNum | Sku | Units | Dollars
```

- First query:

  ```
  select company, storeNum, sku, SUM(units)  AS Units, SUM(dollars) AS dollars
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY company, storeNum, sku
  ```
- Second query:

  ```
  select COUNT(DISTINCT company), COUNT(DISTINCT(storeNum), sku, 
  SUM(units)  AS Units, SUM(dollars) AS dollars
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY sku
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT company) >= 2
  ```

The second query gets totals for a `sku` where at least two `companies` are selling that `sku`. I need a way to be able to find out what company, store make up this list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LISTAGG` to get a comma separated list of companies and list of store as follows.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(company,',') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY company) company_list,
  LISTAGG(StoreNum,',') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY storeNum) Store_list,
  COUNT(DISTINCT company),
  COUNT(DISTINCT storeNum),
  sku,
  SUM(units)   AS Units,
  SUM(dollars) AS dollars
FROM Sales
GROUP BY sku
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT company) >= 2;
```

**Note**: This works for `Oracle 11g` and above.